# Cmake external library .a

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, gnu-make

I have an external library here:

`${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/yaml-cpp/`

It is made by a Makefile: `thirdparty/Makefile`. I am executing that makefile like so:

```
add_custom_target(
   yaml-cpp
   COMMAND make
   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty
)
```

I am then attempting to link the library, which builds to `thirdparty/yaml-cpp/build/libyaml-cpp.a`. **This is the part that is not working**:

```
target_link_libraries(load_balancer_node ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/yaml-cpp/build/libyaml-cpp.a)
```

I get the error:

```
  Target "yaml-cpp" of type UTILITY may not be linked into another target.
  One may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, or to executables with the
  ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.
```

**How do I execute that makefile and link the `.a` file?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it makes sense that cmake can't figure out the dependencies here: it would have to parse the makefile and find the output. You have to tell it the output someone. Nearest I can figure, the best way to do this is to use a custom_command rather than a custom target:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/yaml-cpp/build/libyaml-cpp.a
    COMMAND make
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty)
 add_custom_target(
   yaml-cpp
   DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/yaml-cpp/build/libyaml-cpp.a)
 ...
 add_dependencies(load_balancer_node yaml-cpp)
 target_link_libraries(load_balancer_node ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/yaml-cpp/build/libyaml-cpp.a)
```

I was having linker troubles though (stupid windows machine), but cmake worked and made the libraries before trying to link.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, very close now! Just one problem: `make[3]: *** No rule to make target '../thirdparty/yaml-cpp/build/libyaml-cpp.a', needed by '../bin/load_balancer_node'.  Stop.` Any ideas?

Comment: That should be covered by the `add_dependencies(load_balancer_node yaml-cpp)`. Either that or the 3rd party makefile is dumping the .a in a different location...

Comment: I'm not sure which generator you're using, but if its just make, try "make yaml-cpp" and see if the .a file gets made at  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/yaml-cpp/build/libyaml-cpp.a.